# Renumbering A Column Based On Other Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This table contains Purchase Orders which can have multiple lines per order.  Right now the table appears like this.

| Purchase_OrderNumber | Account_Number | Line_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 174558 | 0000448 | 1 |
| 174558 | 0000448 | 2 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 1 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 1 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 2 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 545 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 26686 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 53481 |
| 175813 | 295812 | 1 |
| 175813 | 295812 | 2 |
| 175813 | 295812 | 5 |

What I need is some SQL statement that will re-number the Line_Number column to based on the Purchase_OrderNumber and Account_Number Columns.  So the end result should look like this:

| Purchase_OrderNumber | Account_Number | Line_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 174558 | 0000448 | 1 |
| 174558 | 0000448 | 2 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 1 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 2 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 3 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 4 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 5 |
| 175812 | 295812 | 6 |
| 175813 | 295812 | 1 |
| 175813 | 295812 | 2 |
| 175813 | 295812 | 3 |

I do not have much experience with SQL.  I could write a Select query to extract the data, write some C# logic to renumber it, and then update the table.  However, I would like to see if it could be simplified by handling it all in an SQL statement.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio...does that answer your question?

Comment: That sort of hints what you are using, but not precisely - SQL Server Management Studio is a client application, it's *not* SQL Server; to know exactly what is installed `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU1) (KB4135048) - 13.0.5149.0 (X64)   May 19 2018 09:41:57   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Is there primary key in table? How will you update values? :)

Comment: There are several more columns than the 3 columns you see here.  It is my understanding that these 3 columns serve as a Superkey to the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select Purchase_OrderNumber, Account_Number,
       row_number() over (partition by Purchase_OrderNumber, Account_Number order by Line_Number) as new_Line_Number
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you are using SQL Server, you can just use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select Purchase_OrderNumber, Account_Number,
             row_number() over (partition by Purchase_OrderNumber, Account_Number order by Line_Number) as new_Line_Number
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set Line_Number = new_Line_Number
    where Line_Number <> new_Line_Number;
```

Comment: This could be a possible solution.  But what I need is to actually change (update) the Line_Number column and not create a new column called new_Line_Number .  There is an external application that is reading from the Line_Number column and building orders based on the Line_Number.